# How to change the Ripple Effect color on a Switch Component in React-Native

Tags: react-native

Using React-Native, I have a simple Switch component but I cannot find a way to change the ripple effect color on Android.

Is there a way to change it using the native component?

```
  <Switch
    onTintColor={'pink'}
    tintColor={'pink'}
    thumbTintColor={'pink'}
  />
```

Comment: It's not possible using native Switch, but there are some pure JS libraries that make this.